# Find an "upper bound" for a given sequence.

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

Let $a_1=5$ and let $$a_{n+1}=\frac{a_n^2}{a_n^2-4a_n+6}$$
Find the biggest integer $m$ not bigger than $a_{2018}$, that is $m\leq a_{2018}$.

My go:
Apparently the limit must satisfy $$l=\frac{l^2}{l^2-4l+6}\Leftrightarrow l=0\vee l=3\vee l=2$$ Computing first few terms i see that $a_n\to 3$ as $n\to\infty$. The sequence seems to converge to 3, so i tried to show that $\forall n\geq 2,a_n\leq3$ proceeding by induction, we find that $a_1=5,a_2=25/11\approx2,27\leq3$. Now let $a_n\leq 3\Rightarrow a_{n+1}=\frac{a_n^2}{a_n^2-4a_n+6}\leq\frac{9}{a_n^2-4a_n+6}$ but here I'm stuck again, no idea what to do with the denominator. Any help appreciated.

Comment: You don't say what $m$ denotes, to relate it to the $n$ in the sequence terms. Also does it mean the biggest *integer* value of $a_n$ or something else? Seems unclear so far...

Comment: I just used $m$ to denote the integer which should satisfy $m\leq a_{2018}$ and i have to find it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose we compute the fixed points of the iteration $x\mapsto\frac{x^2}{x^2-4x+6}$; those fixed points are 0, 2 and 3. Now analyse the *stability* of those fixed points; a fixed point $x_0$ of $x\mapsto f(x)$ is stable (attractive) if $|f'(x_0)|<1$.

The numerator of the derivative of the given map is
$$2x(x^2-4x+6)-x^2(2x-4)$$
and for $x=2$ this is 8, but for $x=3$ this is 0. Furthermore, this expression is non-negative over $[2,3]$. Therefore, since $2<a_2<3$, the sequence monotonically converges to 3 from below after $a_1$, so $m=2$.

Comment: Could you just more specify, what you mean by "fixed point" of a function?

Comment: I'm quite unfamiliar with fixed points and most of your arguments, but could you please show me more thoroughly, how did you come up with the bounds to show the limit is actually 3. I'm still looking for something like $\forall n\in \Bbb{N}:a_n\leq 3$. Or.. since i know the limit is either $0,2$ or $3$ does the fact that from $a_2$ it is strictly greater than two and monotonically increasing allow me to conclude the limit must be $3$? I want to be precise and rigorous.

Comment: @MichalDvořák If you draw the graph of $f(x)=x^2/(x^2-4x+6)$ and the graph of $g(x)=x$, you see there's a pocket between $x=2$ and $x=3$. The $a_i$ enters this pocket at $a_2$. It is trapped within the pocket, because the derivative of $f$ is non-negative, so it cannot escape to the region beyond 3. Therefore it must go to either of the two fixed points that form the pocket's corners, and only 3 is an attractive point out of the two, so the sequence converges to 3 from below.

Comment: I still can't get the argument, what does the positive derivative over $(2,3)$ tell me?

Comment: Yes, but why? Can you explain it in more detailed way?

Comment: @MichalDvořák Essentially it tells you that if $2<a_i<3$ then $a_{1+1}<3$, since 3 is a fixed point.

Comment: Ah, I think im getting it, so if it DID reach $3$ at some point, it would stop here because $3$ is the fixed point and so if $a_i=3$ for some $i$ then $\forall j\geq i: a_j=a_i=3$. That's it?

Comment: @MichalDvořák yes!

Comment: Great! Thanks for your patience, I appreciate it.

Answer (score 2):

Write $b_n=a_n-3$.
Then
$$b_{n+1}=-3+b_{n+1}=\frac{-2a_n^2+12a_n-18}{a_n^2-4a_n+6}
=\frac{-2b_n^2}{b_n^2-2b_n+3}.$$
If $b_n$ is near $0$, then $b_{n+1}$ is negative, and approximately
$-2b_2^2/3$, and so is even nearer zero. Therefore if the sequence $(a_n)$
comes anywhere near $3$, it will converge rapidly to $3$, from below.
It does. Therefore the integer part of $a_{2018}$ will be $2$.

Comment: I can't help myself but i see a circular argument right here, you first assume that it converges to $3$ and conclude, that i converges to 3. I actually managed to show that the sequence IS monotonic increasing for terms in range $(-1,6)$ which is apparently true, but can't seem to prove it is bounded above to conclude the limit is $3$.

Comment: @MichalDvořák See Parcly's argument for more details...

Answer (score 1):

Alt. hint: quite obviously $\;a_n \ne 0\,$, then inverting both sides gives:

$$
\frac{1}{a_{n+1}}=1 - 4 \frac{1}{a_n} + 6 \frac{1}{a_n^2} \quad\iff\quad b_{n+1} = 6 b_n^2 - 4b_n + 1 \quad \style{font-family:inherit}{\text{where}} \;\; b_{n} = \frac{1}{a_n}
$$

Multiplying by $\,6\,$ then gives:

$$
6 b_{n+1} = 36 b_n^2 - 24b_n + 6 = (6 b_n - 2)^2+2 \quad\iff\quad c_{n+1} = c_n^2 \quad \style{font-family:inherit}{\text{where}} \;\; c_{n} = 6 b_n - 2
$$

Since $|c_1| = | 6 / a_1 - 2| = 4/5 \lt 1$ it follows that $\,c_n \to 0\,$ from above, so $\,a_n \to 3\,$ from below, then the same argument already made in other answers applies to show that $\,m = 2\,$.